# PHP - checkdate() doesn't work properly

Tags: php, date

Following my code:

```
<?php
$test = 12;
$test2 = '1a';
$test3 = 1959;
echo checkdate((int)$test, (int)$test2, (int)$test3);
```

It's return true. Assuming that they are POST variable, how to solve it in the most faster way without a regex?

Comment: Casting `'1a'` to an int results in `1`.

Comment: @Stony *"checkdate — Validate a Gregorian date"* - http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php which it is.

Comment: Its going to be implicitly cast regardless, even if you do `checkdate('12, '1a', '1959');` That's just PHP.

Comment: No offense, but why don't you use a date picker? Or simply just an `<input type="date">` ?

Comment: I guess you could always combine that check with [`is_numeric`](http://ch2.php.net/is_numeric) though if the casted input results into a date, why not go with it? It's not really a problem per se.

Comment: @TiborB. because someone can sends a letter instead of a number.

Comment: So, how to validate a date without (int)?

Comment: HTML5 is taking care of that for you. And you can have JavaScript validation. And also you can use checkdate on the received date value. But why would you use 3 text boxes instead of one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are casting the values to check to valid values before checking if they are invalid. That's why you are getting `true` as a result. That `1a` becomes `1` after you cast it to an int. Combined with the other date parts you get 12/01/1959 which is a valid date.

Comment: Si signore, molto bene.

Comment: It's true, but how to validate it without (int)?

Comment: Just don't cast it. That letter will cause the check to fail which is what you want. Or, check for letters in the values *before* you check if the date is valid. If you find one, it's an invalid date.